# Submission of form via javascript has a different result than submission of the form by a real click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write javascript for a chrome extension to submit the following form on a page I am browsing:

```
<form name='cartcheckoutpro' method='POST'action='https://store01.prostores.com/servlet/store/Checkout?cart_id=39064012' style='margin:0px'>
    <input type='image' name='checkout' src='/images/InitialSet/proceedtocheckout.gif' border='0'/><input type='hidden' name="cart_id" value="39064012">
</form>
```

To me, I thought it would be easy with this:

```
document.getElementsByName("cartcheckoutpro")[0].submit();
```

However, when I use javascript to submit the form, the following page is loading differently than if I had clicked the button to continue.  Any thoughts of why I am running in to this issue?

Here are the scripts at the destination page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var email = document.getElementById("customerregistryemail");
        if (email)
            email.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleLogin() {
        document.getElementById('logininfo').style.display = document.getElementById('returning').checked ? "inline" : "none";
    }
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function () {
        toggleLogin();
    });    
    toggleLogin();
</script>
```

Comment: Whats different? And your input type="hidden" has to be closed with />

Comment: If I manually click the button that submits the form, I get the following 3 options: 
(1) I would like to place my order without creating an account.
(2) I am a new customer and I would like to sign up and create an account.
(3) I am a returning customer and would like to use my existing account.

When I simulate submission of the form, I do not get any options, and the following page assumes a variation of option (1).

Comment: Please post some more code, like the script at https://store01.prostores.com/servlet/store/Checkout?cart_id=39064012

Comment: lolcat, I have posted the scripts on the page as requested.  Although, I should note, these scripts are only on the page I get when I manually submit the form by clicking a button.  When simulate the submission of the form via javascript, it takes me to the exact same web address, however, the page is totally different.  I can get the same result if I manually enter the destination URL in my browser.  Is there a value that needs to be transmitted on submission of the form?

Comment: Where do you handle the post parameters? is there a server script? And why do you call toggleLogin() two times? And are you sure that the input fields have exactly the same value when submitting with javascript as when submitting by click?

Comment: lolcat, this is not my page.  I have no control over it.  I am trying to purchase something from a store and simulate as much as possible, as time is very precious!  As to your second point, I think that is what the issue is.  Something appears to be lost when the form is submitted via javascript vs. a manual click.  Is there any way I can contact you directly?  It would be easier to show you if I give you a link to the store.

Comment: Perhaps the cart_id value is not being submitted with the javascript submission of the form?

Comment: I think the cart_id checks, if the form was submitted from teh store itself and not from an other site like yours. The store generates this id, so it is each time different. To get a valid id is nearly impossible, because it changes averey time. You can try to open the real store in a hidden iframe. Then you get the store id using javascript. But I'm not sure if it works.